# Prolems adding a textView inside a addTextChangedListener

Tags: android

I have a listView where each item has a corresponding checkbox. I also have a EditText that serves as a search bar using addTextChangedListener. I made a method that takes a TextView and a LinearLayout (in this case a tab), and adds the TextView to the tab. I call this function twice, once in the method setOnItemClickListener which works fine, and once in the method addTextChangedListener which does not work. My code gets compiled, the application starts, and as soon as I enter text in my search bar, the app quits unexpectedly. Here is the code:

```
public class myList extends Activity {

// Tab Host
TabHost th;
LinearLayout tab1, tab2, tab3;

// List
ListView myListView;
String string_list[] = { "String1", String2", "String3", "String4", "String5", String6", "String7", "String8" };
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
EditText searchBar;

// TextView
TextView tab3TextView1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    // XML File
    setContentView(R.layout.main_list);

    // Sort Array
    Arrays.sort(string_list, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

    // TabHost
    initializeTab();

    // EditText
    searchBar     = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchBar);
    tab3TextView1 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tab3TextView1);

    // ListView
    myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapter    = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, string_list);
    myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    myListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    myListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                int position, long arg3) {
            TextView temp = (TextView) view;

            if (myListView.isItemChecked(position)) {
                TextView newTextView = new TextView(myList.this);
                newTextView.setText(temp.getText());

                // Checks for duplicate TextView
                boolean duplicate = false;
                for(int i = 0; i < tab1.getChildCount(); i++){
                    temp = (TextView) tab1.getChildAt(i);
                    if(newTextView.getText().equals(temp.getText())){
                        duplicate = true;
                    }
                }

                // If no duplicate, add TextView
                if (duplicate == false){
                    addTextView(newTextView, tab1);
                }
            } else {
                TextView newTV = new TextView(myList.this);
                newTV.setText(temp.getText());

                for (int i = 0; i < tab1.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    temp = (TextView) tab1.getChildAt(i);

                    if (newTV.getText().equals(temp.getText())) {
                        tab1.removeView(temp);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    });

    // Search Bar
    searchBar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        TextView newTextView = new TextView(myList.this);
        Map <String, Boolean> myMap;
        ListView tempList;
        TextView tempText;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tempText = new TextView(myList.this);
            myMap  = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

            tempList = new ListView(myList.this);
            tempList = myListView;
            tempList.setFilterText(arg0.toString());

            for(int j = 0; j < tempList.getChildCount()-1; j++){
                tempText = (TextView) tempList.getChildAt(j);
                addTextView(tempText, tab3);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // When user changes the text
            myList.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0);
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}


//Initialize tabs
private void initializeTab() {
    // Tab Host
    th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    th.setup();

    // Linear Layout
    tab1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab1);
    tab2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab2);
    tab3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab3);

    // Tab1
    TabSpec spec1 = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
    spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec1.setIndicator("Favorites");
    th.addTab(spec1);

    // Tab2
    TabSpec spec2 = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
    spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec2.setIndicator("My List");
    th.addTab(spec2);

    // Tab3
    TabSpec spec3 = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
    spec3.setContent(R.id.tab3);
    spec3.setIndicator("Upcoming Release");
    th.addTab(spec3);
}

// Add a TextView
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void addTextView(TextView newTextView, LinearLayout tab){
    newTextView.setTextAppearance(myList.this,
            android.R.style.TextAppearance_Holo_Large);
    newTextView
            .setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tab.addView(newTextView);
}
}
```

By commenting out lines, I know the code fails when I create the new tab. The logCat outputs this error while referring to the line `tab.addView(newTextView)`:

```
03-27 13:12:57.340: E/AndroidRuntime(32500): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-27 13:12:57.340: E/AndroidRuntime(32500): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

How can this be solved? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably solve this by making a new instance of `TextView`

Because you get your `TextView` from a `ListView`, the `TextView` already has a parent and cannot be added to another `ViewGroup`.

You should change

```
tempList = new ListView(myList.this);
        tempList = myListView;
        tempList.setFilterText(arg0.toString());

        for(int j = 0; j < tempList.getChildCount()-1; j++){
            tempText = (TextView) tempList.getChildAt(j);
            addTextView(tempText, tab3);
        }
```

into

```
tempList = new ListView(myList.this);
        tempList = myListView;
        tempList.setFilterText(arg0.toString());

        for(int j = 0; j < tempList.getChildCount()-1; j++){
            tempText = (TextView) tempList.getChildAt(j);
            TextView newTextView = new TextView(myList.this);
            newTextView.setText(tempText.getText());

            addTextView(newTextView, tab3);
        }
```

I think that should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add another view's child element to TAB.You can't add another child.Create similar textview and add it to TAB or Remove that textview from listview and add it to TAB.

in that loop 
add following code.

```
       for(int j = 0; j < tempList.getChildCount()-1; j++){
          if( tempList.getChildAt(j) instanceOf TextView){
        tempText = (TextView) tempList.getChildAt(j);
        TextView tempView = new TextView(yourclass.this);
         tempView.setText(tempText.getText());
        addTextView(tempView , tab3);
          }
    }
```